# Top is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Heres the code:

```
$('> li', this).each(function (index) {
    var top_space = $(this).css('padding-top');
    $(this).prepend('<div></div>');
    $('> div', this).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: -top_space,
        width: "100%",
        height: top_space,
            "z-index": 0
    });
});
```

Here's the result in inspect element:

---

[image]

---

As you can see there is no top attribute, but when I remove the negative sign...

---

[image]

---

There's a top attribute but not working, it's still in top:0

---

[image]

---

I've been stuck for almost an hour now, can't figure out why. What am I missing?

Comment: can you post more html code ? to makes the code clear

Comment: Did you check the variable 'top_space' is getting value??

Comment: top space is a `string` when you get the css it will be eg. `200px`, then you're assigning `-"200px"`. that is not valid, you should parseInt the value and append "px" to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
top: "-" + top_space,
```

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenation `+` operator

```
top:  "-" + top_space
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NL2Z/)

Answer (score 1):

Your top_space will be string so you can't make it like "-top_space"

```
Try: -(parseInt(top_space))
```